# Sound issue with Logitech G633 headset

Tags: release-juno, sound

When I start up my PC and Elementary OS the headset makes the "now connected" sound and if I use the volume control on the headset it makes the beeps it's supposed to to acknowledge that sound level is being changed. However, no other sound works on the system, from any source.

If I go to sound settings and test speakers, I get no sound. BUT. When I change the speaker balance off-center and test speakers sound starts working, and after this it works system-wide. I have to do this every reboot to get sound working from said headset, though.

Just wondering if this is a known issue and if there's a way I could fix this? The workaround isn't a big deal honestly but it feels a bit silly.